# How to get a one page application (Vue.js) indexed by search engines

Tags: html, search, webpack, seo, vue.js

I'm building a one-page application using Vue.js and Webpack for bundling the client-side (HTML, JS, all in one file).

It seems that search engines, such as Google, are having trouble indexing the content, since it's only rendered through that bundle file, and doesn't exist on the html files (attached example).

My question is - how can I make Google index my app's content?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/build.js?1500"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/can-now-trust-google-crawl-ajax-sites-235267

Comment: My main issue is about the static text that stay in build.js, Google doesn't index it. after I solved it i'll check what's happen with the ajax responses. thank for helping

Comment: Just for reference, there is a Nov/2016 google webmaster blog post on [Building Indexable Progressive Web Apps](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/11/building-indexable-progressive-web-apps.html)

Comment: Also, [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) might provide valuable insights.